# WpfCombo box itemsource binding call back

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have a combobox where it binded to view model  list property. This list property then calls to the async function in data layer.

I wanted to set the selected index property of the combobox to "zero" I.e selected index=0;

Real scenario is data is perfectly loading but even after I set selected index property it is not applying since async call.
Please let me know any callback method after property bonded.

Comment: please let us know what you have tried so far

Comment: I tried IsAsync=true property in itemsource. But it is working sometime but not always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a sample application

ViewModel

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<string> _source;
    private object _lock = new object();

    public IEnumerable<string> Source
    {
        get { return _source; }
    }

    public String SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _source = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_source, _lock);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PopulateSourceAsunc());
    }

    private void PopulateSourceAsunc()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            _source.Add("Test " + i.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        //SelectedItem = _source[6];
        SelectedIndex = 5;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
```

`BindingOperations` class is in the namespace of `System.Windows.Data`

Comment: Thanks a lot Sandesh. Also Why do we use <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>? without this also it is working.

Comment: Yeah it will work. For such small list of items it does not make a difference. It will improve the performance greatly when you have hundred's of item in your ComboBox